# Phonegap FileTransfer appears to do nothing in android

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

I'm having problems with the Phonegap FileTransfer API. Currently I'm trying to run the example code below:

```
        saveFile: function (filepath,location, filetype) {
            console.log("FUNCTION BEING CALLED");
            var self = this;
            //filepath is path to the internets file
            //location is where on the device the file will be stored
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileTransfer.download(filepath,self.rootPath + location + '.' + filetype,
                function (entry) {
                    console.log('############# DOWNLOAD WORKS ##############');
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log('############# DOWNLOAD FAILS ##############');
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                }
            )
        }
```

Currently, nothing at all appears to be happening. No errors are flagged, and the callbacks don't appear to be firing. All I get is the initial console.log of "FUNCTION BEING CALLED".

I've double checked, and can confirm that I'm including the cordova js file, (`cordova-2.4.0.js`).

If it matters, I've tried this on the Android Emulator, a HTC One X and a Samsung Galaxy S3, all with the same results.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Edit: I also felt I should mention that it's all running in an Angular JS app as well.

Comment: try to console.log(self.rootPath + location + '.' + filetype); and check what you get

Comment: This gives me `/test_app/test_pdf.pdf`. I've also tried it without the root, which gives me `test_pdf.pdf`. Could this be the cause of the problem? Do I need to specify a specific path?

Comment: I've also tried with `file:///sdcard/theFile.pdf` and I'm still getting nothing

Answer (score 0):

this  is how i am doing it in my project

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
  }
 function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    window.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    //create directory test_app
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("test_app", {
        create : true,
        exclusive : false
    }, dirWallpaper, fail);

 function fail(evt) {

 }

function dirWallpaper(entry) {
    //save the directory path
    window.testDir = entry;
}
//now download file to that location
saveFile: function (filepath,location, filetype) {
        console.log("FUNCTION BEING CALLED");
        var self = this;
        //filepath is path to the internets file
        //location is where on the device the file will be stored
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var path = window.testDir.fullPath + "/test_pdf."+ filetype;
        fileTransfer.download(filepath,path,
            function (entry) {
                console.log('############# DOWNLOAD WORKS ##############');
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('############# DOWNLOAD FAILS ##############');
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            }
        )
    }
```

try like this and let me know.

Comment: It appears that my issue may be more fundamental than I first thought. It turns out the `deviceready` event is never firing for me, and `window.requestFileSystem()` also does absolutely nothing. After a bit of digging, and putting console.logs in the cordova.js, I've found that the javascript is working fine, but everything stops when it hits the `exec()` function. So this leads me to beleive that phonegap itself isn't working properly?

Comment: then i guess there is problem with the project creation try to download the latest phonegap and create project for android with the instruction they provided on their site.

Comment: I solved my problem. In case you were interested, when I set up this project, I copied the code from the iOS version, which means I was trying to run the app the the iOS version of cordova.js, and not the android one. A clear case of PEBKAC, I'm afraid. Many thanks for your assistance though